# Laptop doesn' t want to wake up

Tags: virtual-machine, bios, sleep

My laptop (Notebook HP Pavilion g7t-1100 CTO) have been working fine till today, I enabled Virtual Technology in BIOS and from that time laptop doesn't want to wake up after I slept it. When I disable VT it works fine again. I have installed two softwares: Windows 7 and Ubuntu and on both of them it doesn't want to wake up. Do you have any ideas how I can fix it?

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me about two months ago. Don't worry chances are that it is locked up. If your computer has an external battery pull it out.

If your computer doesn't have a battery, close it flip it upside-down, then there is a pin hole. if your computer has this use a paperclip or staple to press the button inside the hole. (kinda like the reset buttons on old hand-held football games).

If this doesn't work, take it to best buy (hear me out) they'll fix it for free if all they have to do is a restart. Just make sure you ask if its free.